# changing mouse cursor in chromiumwebbrowser DragEnter event in WPF

Tags: cefsharp

we are using chromiumwebbrowser in WPf application, added DragEnter event handler to the chromiumwebbrowser and call come to us.

wanted to change the cursor,

```
private void Browser_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var currCursor = Browser.Cursor;
            if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Move)
            {
                
               //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
                // Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Hand);
                Debug.Write("DragDropEffects.Move\n");
            }
            else
                Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Hand);

            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Pen;
            Browser.Cursor = Cursors.Pen;
            //Mouse.Capture(Browse);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

nothing works, could some help would solve this issue

Comment: Is the event handler fired when you attach the debugger? From memory the event isn't by default as it's handed internally.  Try using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.addhandler?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_UIElement_AddHandler_System_Windows_RoutedEvent_System_Delegate_System_Boolean_ and specify handledEventsToo true